# Tooltip from React-Bootstrap's OverlayTrigger appears after closing the Modal

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, react-bootstrap

Description:
I'm using React-Bootstrap and encountering an issue with the OverlayTrigger. I have a button that opens a Modal, and the overlay for this button is a Tooltip. The problem is that after closing the Modal, the Tooltip instantly appears as if the mouse is still hovering over the button. I would like to know how I can prevent this undesired behavior.

Example code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip, Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <OverlayTrigger
        overlay={<Tooltip>My Tooltip</Tooltip>}
        delay={{ show: 250, hide: 0 }}
      >
        <Button onClick={handleOpenModal}>Open Modal</Button>
      </OverlayTrigger>

      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleCloseModal}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal Title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {/* Modal Content */}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={handleCloseModal}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Open the Modal by clicking the "Open Modal" button.
Close the Modal by clicking the "Close" button.
Observe that the Tooltip appears instantly after closing the Modal.

Expected result:

The Tooltip should not appear after closing the Modal. The correct behavior would be to display the Tooltip only when the mouse is hovering over the button.

What I've tried:

I attempted to add an event to hide the Tooltip after closing the Modal, but I was not successful.
I checked the React-Bootstrap documentation and searched forums and related discussions, but I couldn't find a solution for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the `trigger` prop of [OverlayTrigger](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger-props) is `['hover', 'focus']` so the tooltip will display both when hovered over and focussed on.

To change this so that you only get the tooltip on hover you can set the value of `trigger` to `['hover']`:

```
<OverlayTrigger
  ...
  trigger={["hover"]}
>
  <Button onClick={handleOpenModal}>Open Modal</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

There's a working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-frog-6fiyf2?file=/src/App.js) - when the close the modal the button still has focus, but the tooltip is not displayed unless you hover your mouse over the button.